# How can I mark a directory in an RPM as no longer being managed by RPM

Tags: rpm

So I have this issue where in version "1" of an RPM there is a symbolic directory. Let's just call it "/foo". To clarify, "/foo" is defined in version "1"'s RPM. In version "2" I wish to programattically create "/foo" in a postinstall script. But when I remove "/foo" from my RPM's spec it will erase "/foo" after the postinstall script had already run. Is there a way to prevent this? That is tell RPM not to erase "/foo" even though it's no longer being managed by RPM?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean during an upgrade operation. If so, RPM is properly cleaning up the old files. You can try to drop a non-registered file into the directory (via your `%postinstall`). "`echo > /foo/.keepdir`" or something like that. Then it might leave it alone, since it doesn't recognize the file and shouldn't erase files that aren't listed in the `%files` section of version 1.

I will, however, note that if you create and use the directory `/foo`, you *should* have it claimed by your package, so that when somebody comes along and tries "`rpm -q --whatprovides /foo`" they can tell where it came from and who uses it.

Comment: Is there a way to claim it without creating it? It feels a bit hacky to create a directory only to erase it and then point it somewhere else. This is what I'm doing at the moment.

Basically to clarify the situation, a previous developer created a directory and populated it with libraries for another piece of software. This coupled the two pieces and versions of the software together. What my postinstall script does is locate to see if the other software is in a well known location and then symlink to it rather that provide my own hardcoded binaries.

Comment: @JasonThompson You can "claim" file by using %ghost directive in %files sectiom. See http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can create RPM version 1.1 without /foo , upgrade to 1.1 and then upgrade to 2.

Comment: While that certainly does work, it creates more problems than it solves. Trying to tell a client to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1 is hard enough. Having them upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1 to 1.2 is impossible. Most sysadmin would see the two RPMs and then go from 1.0->1.2 without thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%posttrans` instead of `%post` to fix this. However be advised that posttrans  scriptlets should be written in pure lua. This is because they can in theory run in kickstart without any shell/libraries besides what is in RPM itself.

Full order of scriptlets (as taken from [Fedora Packaging Guidelines](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aScriptletSnippets)) is as follows:

1. %pretrans of new package
2. %pre of new package
3. (package install)
4. %post of new package
5. %triggerin of other packages (set off by installing new package)
6. %triggerin of new package (if any are true)
7. %triggerun of old package (if it's set off by uninstalling the old package)
8. %triggerun of other packages (set off by uninstalling old package)
9. %preun of old package
10. (removal of old package)
11. %postun of old package
12. %triggerpostun of old package (if it's set off by uninstalling the old package)
13. %triggerpostun of other packages (if they're setu off by uninstalling the old package)
14. %posttrans of new package

I will note that any complicated work in posttrans is not generally advised. Any problems you introduce in %posttrans will be very hard to fix during update. Instead, you could supply a support script that the administrator is supposed to run after update instead. Application can gracefully error out and remind them to do that (in some cases that's not possible I guess, but usually there is a way to do it nicely). Or app itself can detect this and properly symlink/copy dependencies as needed.

Aand a final warning: There is a problem in RPM with handling updates where one RPM has symlink to a directory and new RPM has directory instead (or reversed). If you see transaction errors, this might be the likely culprit. This is something that can really be fixed only in %pretrans/%posttrans scriptlets

Answer (score -1):

Try marking foo as a %config(noreplace) file in the %files section of the spec file.  This will keep rpm from modifying the file during upgrades.

Comment: %config(noreplace) cannot be applied to directories, only files.